# inner join instead of cross join JPA criteria query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I would like to make that request

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(alumni.id), 
    undergrad_school.NAME 
FROM
    undergrad_school 
INNER JOIN 
    alumni ON alumni.undergrad_school_id = undergrad_school.id 
GROUP BY 
    undergrad_school_id;
```

But with Jpa criteria query (with Spring boot), I tried to do something like :

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteria = builder.createQuery(Object[].class);
    Root<Alumni> alumniRoot = criteria.from(Alumni.class);
    Root<UndergradSchool> schoolRoot = criteria.from(UndergradSchool.class);

    criteria.groupBy(schoolRoot.get("id"));
    criteria.multiselect(schoolRoot.get("name"), builder.count(alumniRoot)).distinct(true);
```

The query generated uses a cross join :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    undergrads1_.NAME  AS col_0_0_, 
    COUNT(alumni0_.id) AS col_1_0_ 
FROM   
    alumni alumni0_ 
CROSS JOIN 
    undergrad_school undergrads1_ 
GROUP BY 
    undergrads1_.id
```

So my question is, how can i do the first request with Criteria query. 
The final goal is to count the number of alumni by undergrad school.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The join that you show is an entity join, for which there is no way to express it in the JPA Criteria API. Instead, you will have to use an association join. Assuming such an association is present on the entity, i.e. `Alumni.undergradSchool` exists and is mapped, you could do:

```java
Join<UndergradSchool> schoolRoot = alumniRoot.join(alumniRoot.get(Alumni_.undergradSchool));
```

Or without static metamodel:

```java
Join<UndergradSchool> schoolRoot = alumniRoot.join(alumniRoot.get("undergradSchool"));
```

A `Join` is also a `Root`, but also has `Join` related methods, such as `Join.on(Predicate)` which allows you to specify an additional ON clause. The relation between the alumni and the undergrad school however is already restricted using this type of join.

Comment: How do you obtain the Alumni_. undergradSchool, I often see that way to get class properties but it dosen't work for me ?

Comment: None of your answers work, in the first Alumni_.  is not found, in the second "alumniRoot.get("undergradSchool")" is not valid for the method join. But I can do `Join<Alumni, UndergradSchool> schoolRoot = alumniRoot.join(alumniModel.getSingularAttribute("undergradSchool", UndergradSchool.class));`

Comment: @planingEmployer , you need to generate the static metamodel to get the first one to work, as the gentleman who answered your question mentioned. Details are available here: https://hibernate.org/orm/tooling/